# Prevent playing of animation in different divs(having same animation effect) loading at different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a landing page that uses three divs. Out of three only one div is set to display at any specific screen size. Each div loads at a specific screen size using media queries.

Div1 ---> upto 800px width

Div2 ---> Between 801px to 1400px width

Div3 ---> Above 1400px width

Every time the page load the background image in my div change from a black and white image to a color image using the CSS filters

The problem arises when I resize my windows. For example, on resizing my window to a smaller screen size/window size; Div2  becomes set to display:none and Div1 is now visible. As a result since the div is loaded, it loads the black and white to color CSS filter effect once again. However this effect is only supposed to play once during page load and not when the browser is resized or if my ipad is rotated(the screen width increases).

Can anyone suggest me a solutions for this. I was thinking of preventing any animations play after a certain specified time (the time that it takes the background animation to play from page load). Can anyone guide me to how this can be done or help with a better solution

Comment: Have you tried using CSS media queries?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you show your code.

Comment: Maybe using media queries will be of some use? I'm sure you can play around with this maybe find a way to clean it up but isn't an example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vygvjW

Comment: @henrikstroem I have pasted my code here. Please ignore the last two animation codes, they are just a repetition. I know pastebin is not the best place to paste it. But since i m working in wordpress on a theme, i just couldn't recreate it in a site like codepen
http://pastebin.com/s9c2tHq5

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it could be adding a CSS class `.animate` on parent element and remove that class once CSS filter transition ended. It could be done via `transitionend` event. More about it here: https://jonsuh.com/blog/detect-the-end-of-css-animations-and-transitions-with-javascript/
Then, in your CSS you could create CSS filter effect on  `.animate .div1 {...}` selector only.

Comment: Thank you for that. I already have a parent container by the class name of "animame" and I already use a script to load the animation only when the page loads.
However my core strength is just CSS. Can you tell me how can add that in the script below (used for loading when the page starts). It there a way to add the class aniname back after 4 secconds as all my animations end then. I have already used the CSS for aninamtion set to none for the class aniname


<script>
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery("div").removeClass("aniname");
});
</script>